# Xamarin forms Picker Binding error

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a picker control:

```
<Picker Title="Number of People" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding SomeList, Source={x:Static local:MyModelHandler.MyModel}}" 
            SelectedItem="{Binding SomeListSelectedIndex, Source={x:Static local:MyModelHandler.MyModel}}">
    </Picker>
```

when trying to build i get "No property, bindable property, or event found for 'ItemsSource'" error.

Above that i have a label:

```
<Label Text ="{Binding SomeLabel, Source={x:Static local:MyModelHandler.MyModel}, Mode=OneWay}"></Label>
```

And that binding works perfectly

MyModelHandler is an static class that allowes only one Model

```
public static class MyModelHandler
{
    private static MyModel myModel = new MyModel();

    public static MyModel MyModel
    {
        get
        {
            return myModel;
        }
    }
}
```

And Model is simple:

```
public class MyModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private int selectedNumber = 1;
    private string someLabel = "";

    public IList<int> SomeList
    {
        get
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToList();
        }
    }

    public int SomeListSelectedIndex
    {
        get
        {
            return SomeList.IndexOf(this.selectedNumberOfPeople);
        }
        set
        {
            this.selectedNumber = SomeList[value];
        }
    }

        public double SomeLabel
        {
            get
            {
                return this.someLabel;
            }
            set
            {
                this.someLabel= value;
            }
        }


    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
     }
...
}
```

Edit: Using Xamarin 4.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might check your Xamarin.Forms version.

The ItemsSource property was introduced in Xamarin.Forms 2.3.4.184-pre1, see release notes here:

https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/xamarin-forms/xamarin-forms-2.3/2.3.4-stable/#2.3.4.184-pre1.

If you are using an older Xamarin.Forms version you will get the Xamarin.Forms XAML error "No property, bindable property, or event found for 'ItemsSource'".

Comment: Your answer was very helpful, and it led me to my problem. My Visual Studio was reporting that biggest Xamarin.forms version was instaled, and that there are no newer releases. Solution was update VS (and with that Xamarin), and that allowed me to install newer version of Xamarin Forms

Answer (score 1):

That is a very strange way to set up the binding context for a view. The fact you have to specify the source for each element adds a lot of extra boilerplate code.

Try setting the bindingcontext to the model in the the view constructor

```
BindingContext = new MyModel ();
```

Then the XAML becomes

```
<Picker Title="Number of People" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding SomeList}" 
        SelectedItem="{Binding SomeListSelectedIndex}">
</Picker>
```

Or use a proper MVVM framework and save yourself a lot of grief. I can recommend FreshMvvm.

https://github.com/rid00z/FreshMvvm